# How do I validate a field in a jelly form that depends on the form state?

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jelly

I'm building a Jenkins plugin that accesses a remote server. As part of the configuration, the user needs to enter a URL for the server and provide an access key. Then the plugin will retrieve a list of resources from the server, and the user needs to select the appropriate one from an html `select` input.

I'm using the /lib/form namespace to create the `config.jelly` file, and the select is being populated using the  tag:

`<f:entry title="Resource" field="resource">
    <f:select />
</f:entry>`

In my Descriptor class, I have a method:

`doFillResourceItems(@QueryParamter final String url, @QueryParameter final String key)`

and the stapler appears to call the method any time the `onchange` event is triggered by the browser (as expected).

My problem is in the `doCheckResource(@QueryParameter final String value)` method. It would be helpful to have access to the `ListBoxModel` object that was returned by the `doFillResourceItems()` method, as the error message I want to display to the user should be different, depending on whether the plugin was able to retrieve the list of resources or not. One option would be to simply inject the `url` and `key` fields into the `doCheckResource` method as well, and try again, but them I'm retrieving the list of resources twice, which isn't ideal.

What do I need to do in order to have Stapler inject that previously retrieved `ListBoxModel` object into the validation method call?